# Java choose correct SWT at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, classloader

I am writing a cross-platform program, and SWT is part of it.

as far as i know i have to select the right SWT library to the right platform and architecture(32 or 64 bit)

so, i need to load SWT jar file at runtime to achieve this. Actually i found a way to do this, but i haven't accomplished it yet.

I take steps following this site 
https://www.chrisnewland.com/select-correct-swt-jar-for-your-os-and-jvm-at-runtime-191

but when i run(in eclipse) i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Display cannot be resolved to a type
    Display cannot be resolved to a type
    Shell cannot be resolved to a type
    Shell cannot be resolved to a type
```

Actually, here is the code that i use to test if dynamic loading is success.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;


public class AddJarAtRuntime {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File swtJar = null;
    swtJar = new File("lib/swt-win-x64.jar"); 
    if(swtJar == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    addJarToClasspath(swtJar);

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.setText("Hello, world!");

    shell.open();
    // Set up the event loop.
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        // If no more entries in the event queue
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
}


public static void addJarToClasspath(File jarFile) 
{ 
   try 
   { 
       URL url = jarFile.toURI().toURL(); 
       URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(); 
       Class<?> urlClass = URLClassLoader.class; 
       Method method = urlClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class<?>[] { URL.class }); 
       method.setAccessible(true);         
       method.invoke(urlClassLoader, new Object[] { url });             
   } 
   catch (Throwable t) 
   { 
       t.printStackTrace(); 
   } 
}

}
```

when i compile i get an the errors on lines

```
Display display = new Display();
```

and

```
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
```

seems like it can't detect the jar file.

i tried to export this project out but it doesn't work too.

Does anybody have idea how i can export the project or make it run correctly?

PS. It would be helpful if somebody provides me the step by step solution.

thanks

Comment: You have to have a SWT jar in your classpath when you compile this. If you get compile errors Java will not run your code.

Comment: I think i found the mistake. I didn't read carefully enough that in the web site said i have to call the class that imports org.eclipse...swt after i have already done loading the swt Library. but in the sample code i instead call and initiate in the same class. So, after i separate them i can run them